# Create softlink to Onedrive folder in admin root

Tags: symbolic-link

I am using onedrive (Onedrive is terminal based sync application used to sync onedrive from local folder to onedrive in cloud from microsoft) to sync folders. Since, it is in root folder, it asks for permission everytime I open and I also can't directly download files into this folder as it is not shown in short cup.
The current folder path is in admin:///root/Onedrive.
So, I am trying to create the symbolic link by using ln -s /root/OneDrive /home/myFolder/OneDrive.
But it doesn't work. Error message says this link can't be used because its target doesn't exist. The created shortcut link is broken and says target doesn't exist.
How may I solve this issue?

Comment: "It doesn't work". Can you indicate the error message issues by the ln command? Once, you mention OneDrive, another time Onedrive. What is it? Please use "edit" to complete your question.

Comment: @vanadium Error message says this link can't be used because its target doesn't exist. Onedrive is terminal based sync application used to sync onedrive from local folder to onedrive in cloud from microsoft.

Comment: What is the error message when you create the link? Is it /root/Onedrive or /root/OneDrive? Apart from that, the approach of storing user files under /root is not the most obvious one. Still, you should be able to create the link, but you may not be able to access the link as normal user.

Comment: Link does get created. But when open the link by clicking the icon, I get the link can not be used because target doesn't exist message. It was automatically created in that location when I installed onedrive.

Comment: It seems we can configure the path location from the onedrive settings itself. Thank you.